# How to link a string property from string.xml in android fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to android and this may be odd that I can't link a string property. But I tried from google but no luck. I have a fragment where I need to use a URL which I have defined in string.xml. But I can't link it in my fragment class. Can anybody please help me on this please ?!!! Here are my attempts below :

My property in string.xml file >>>

```
<string name="url">http://ip/gaanbaajna/</string>
```

My java code to link (the class extends Fragment) >>>

```
private String curURL = getString(R.string.url);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Correct way

```
private String curURL = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.url);
```

Comment: @SumonBappi where you added? show me your code. add this under `onCreateView(.....)`

Comment: Yes, it works in onCreateView(). I was initializing it at class level. thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
private String curURL = getResources().getString(R.string.url);
```